# Is there a pandas function to repeat rows at set time intervals?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which contains data and the datetime range over which it applies:

```
data | start_time    | end_time
0    | 2020-01-01-00 | 2020-01-01-02
1    | 2020-01-01-05 | 2020-01-01-08
```

I'd like to translate the data to an hourly time series, so it ends up as follows:

```
data | time    
0    | 2020-01-01-00
0    | 2020-01-01-01
0    | 2020-01-01-02
1    | 2020-01-01-05
1    | 2020-01-01-06
1    | 2020-01-01-07
1    | 2020-01-01-08
```

I could brute force my way through this, but was wondering if there is built in functionality in pandas dataframes I could explore to help achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `pandas.date_range` and `pandas.DataFrame.explode`:

```
df['time'] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x['start_time'], x['end_time'], freq='1H'), 1)
print(df.explode('time'))
```

Output:

```
   data     start_time       end_time                time
0     0  2020-01-01-00  2020-01-01-02 2020-01-01 00:00:00
0     0  2020-01-01-00  2020-01-01-02 2020-01-01 01:00:00
0     0  2020-01-01-00  2020-01-01-02 2020-01-01 02:00:00
1     1  2020-01-01-05  2020-01-01-08 2020-01-01 05:00:00
1     1  2020-01-01-05  2020-01-01-08 2020-01-01 06:00:00
1     1  2020-01-01-05  2020-01-01-08 2020-01-01 07:00:00
1     1  2020-01-01-05  2020-01-01-08 2020-01-01 08:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try to create a temporal time serie dataframe and merge with yours, then select the relevant. As a suggestion:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'data': [0, 1],'start_time': ['2020-01-01-00', '2020-01-01-05'],\
               'end_time': ['2020-01-01-02', '2020-01-01-08']})

# Create a temporal time serie dataframe
df_ts = pd.DataFrame({'start_time': pd.date_range(df.start_time.min(), df.end_time.max(), freq='h')\
                              .strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H')})
# Merge and pad the value between start & end time
new_df = df_ts.merge(df, how='left').fillna(method='pad')

# Select the relevant rows
new_df = new_df.loc[new_df.start_time <= new_df.end_time, ['data','start_time']]\
                .rename(columns={'start_time': 'time'})
new_df

data           time
 0.0  2020-01-01-00
 0.0  2020-01-01-01
 0.0  2020-01-01-02
 1.0  2020-01-01-05
 1.0  2020-01-01-06
 1.0  2020-01-01-07
 1.0  2020-01-01-08
```